# How can filter Function be used between 2 datasets in R Studio?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

If I generate a sample of 30 from a data frame that has 50 observations, how can I separate the remaining 20 from the data frame of 50 using `filter` function? Is it possible to use the `filter` function between two data frames? If so, then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
# dummy data
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                  y = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create a sample index, set a seed for reproducibility.

```
set.seed(1)
idx <- sort(sample(1:nrow(dat), size = 6, replace = FALSE))
idx
#[1] 2 3 4 5 7 8
```

Subset your data frame

```
dat[idx, ]
#  x y
#2 2 b
#3 3 c
#4 4 d
#5 5 e
#7 7 g
#8 8 h
```

Get the rows that are not in `idx`

```
dat[-idx, ]
#    x y
#1   1 a
#6   6 f
#9   9 i
#10 10 j
```